# Using CSS attr() with styled components in react Hooks

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, attributes, styled-components

I am trying to use attribute of SkillPer component  `pers={80}` in css content `attr` function like so:

`content: attr(pers) "%";`

But `content: attr()` cannot get the attributes of `<SkillPer pers={80}></SkillPer>`

Am I missing something there? please help!

```js
<SkillBar className="skill-bar">
    <SkillPer
        className="skill-per"
        pers={80}
        style={{ maxWidth: "80%" }}
    ></SkillPer>
</SkillBar>

export const SkillPer = styled.div`
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: var(--color-green);
    animation: ${fillBars} 2.5s 1;
    position: relative;
    &::before {
        content: attr(pers) "%"; // here
        position: absolute;
        padding: 4px 6px;
        background-color: #333;
        color: var(--color-white);
        font-size: 15px;
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(200%);
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pers` is a prop, so you can access the props in the style body. I believe this should work for you.

```
export const SkillPer = styled.div`
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: var(--color-green);
  animation: ${fillBars} 2.5s 1;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: ${({ pers }) => `"${pers} %"`};
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-size: 15px;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(200%);
  }
`;
```

Comment: hi, I tried this one also but it is not working ((

Comment: @BoburmirzoMuhibullaev Oh, I see, looks like I forgot the quotes, try `content: ${({ pers }) => \`"${pers} %"\`};` instead. I just tested this in a codesandbox and it renders.

Comment: @BoburmirzoMuhibullaev https://codesandbox.io/s/using-css-attr-with-styled-components-in-react-hooks-cyk6q